# How to disable generating nunit-agent log file when running tests with nunit3-console

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I have a question regarding the nunit3-console. When running tests through it I am observing a generation of log files like internal-trace and nunit-agent text files.

I was able to disable the generation of the internal-trace with the --trace=off option but for each run having the test .dll specified I am noticing a nunit-agentNumber.txt file generated.

My question is, is this a problem? More specifically for CI/CD and is there an option to disable this? Or clean it at least after each run.

Comment: Having the same issue and came here through Google. Hopefully in a later release, setting `--trace=Off` will also automatically disable the generation of "nunit-agent_<number>.txt" files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 3.15 of the engine introduced a new internal feature, allowing code to change the level of debugging dynamically. (Not yet exposed to users, but intended to be eventually)

As a side effect, it looks as if empty log files are being created. For the moment, the only way to avoid this is to go back to the previous release.

A fix was created in the development code for version 4.0, but has not been ported back to the version 3 code. A bug report might help with that. :-)

Comment: Thank you Charlie!

Switching back to 3.14 resolved this as you mentioned.

Will try to log a bug report this weekend so it can get more attention and a possible fix.
Thanks again for the fast response! :)

Comment: Has this bug been reported or fixed?  It still exists in version 3.15.2.

Comment: It's fixed in 3.16

Answer (score 0):

BTW, This got un-fixed in ConsoleRunner v3.17.0.  Version 3.16.3 still doesn't spam you, though...